# Django API raises an error "No such file or directory: 'manage.py'" when requested

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py, manage.py

This might seem like an already asked question but I have searched for an answer for a week now and got nothing.
The problem is I have developed an API using Django which is hosted on a server. Now when I run the following command to initiate the server :

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
```

The server starts as usual. Its only when I send request to the server via "Postman" that I see the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'manage.py'
```

The strange thing is there is no error in running the server but only when I send a request to it. Also I have many more Django APIs running on the same server with same **python version(Python 3.4.3)** and same virtual environment (but different port) that are running just fine.

Full error traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 98, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 105, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 317, in main
    python_reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 296, in python_reloader
    reloader_thread()
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 274, in reloader_thread
    change = fn()
  File "/home/ubuntu/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 204, in code_changed
    stat = os.stat(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'manage.py'
```

Things I have tried:

- I have tried changing the **!#** as suggested on various posts.
- I have tried using dos2unix to convert the file to unix format(server on which my API is hosted is linux based).
- I even have tried to create a new Django project.
- And yes I'm running manage.py from the correct directory.
- I have also tried making manage.py executable by :

  chmod +x manage.py

Nothing worked for me so far. Am I missing something?

Comment: DO NOT use the dev server for production !!! it's a DEVELOPPER tool only, it's absolutely NOT made to be used in production. Use a proper frontend web server and wsgi connector instead.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm not quite sure what you are suggesting. Can you be more clear?. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you STOP USING THE DEVSERVER in production - it was never designed for this - and USE A PROPER DEPLOYMENT SETUP instead (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/).